# Push Notifications to Socket IO (nodeJS) to Slack

Tags: node.js, acumatica, slack

I'm trying to implement Push Notifications from Acumatica to my own NodeJS Server using SocketIO to get real-time notifications.

I am using the Webhook Type to send Data to Slack, unfortunately Slack only needed 
"text" parameter to post on their webhook.

Acumatica has its own sets of parameters. I've looked up on how to create class-based Notification Structure defined by Acumatica Documentation, I can't find a way to compress all the JSON returned by the Data Query into "text" params, or any other way to customize the data query returned by Acumatica.

I'm trying to look into other Push Notification Methods in Acumatica.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 possibilities to do:

1. you can write your own service to transfer acumatica push notifications to slack form and resend them to slack.
2. you can customize acumatica and add there your own hooktype.
   In this case you should implement a pair of interfaces: `IPushNotificationSender` and `IPushNotificationSenderFactory`

this hook will be automatically added to your hook type selector.